# Formatar dados e salvar em txt com php

Tags: php, txt

O objetivo é extrair dados da base e salvar em arquivo txt...
O script funciona corretamente quando insiro somente $log (nome) na linha

```
if (!fwrite($savelog, $log))
```

na tentativa de adicionar `$log2 (numero)`

```
if (!fwrite($savelog, $log, $log2))
```

acusa erro

> ( Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in)

qual a solução para armazenar os dois dados no txt com suas devidas formatações `(str_pad)` ?

```
<?php

include "conexao.php";

$querymail = mysql_query("select nome,numero from listagem");
fopen("listar.txt", "w+");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($querymail)) {
$log = str_pad($data[nome], 30, " ", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
$log2 = str_pad($data[numero], 30, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
if (!$savelog = fopen('listar.txt', "a")) 
{ exit; }
if (!fwrite($savelog, $log, $log2))
{ exit; fclose($savelog); }
}
?>
<a href="listar.txt">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendi o seu uso do `fwrite`, conforme a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) o uso é este:

```
int fwrite ( resource $handle , string $string [, int $length ] )
```

O terceiro parâmetro é esperado um numero inteiro e não uma string.

Se o argumento `$length` for usado, a escrita do documento irá parar depois que comprimento `bytes` tenham sido escritos ou o final da string seja alcançado, o que vier primeiro.

Ou seja é um "limitador" de escrita.

Se o seu objetivo é gravar o conteudo de `$log2 = str_pad($data[numero], 30, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);` no .txt faça assim:

```
if ($savelog = fopen('listar.txt', "a")) {
    fwrite($savelog, $log);
    fwrite($savelog, $log2);
    fclose($savelog);
}
```

Com concatenação:

```
if ($savelog = fopen('listar.txt', "a")) {
    fwrite($savelog, $log . $log2);
    fclose($savelog);
}
```

Ou com quebra de linha:

```
if ($savelog = fopen('listar.txt', "a")) {
    fwrite($savelog, $log . PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($savelog, $log2);
    fclose($savelog);
}
```

Com concatenação:

```
if ($savelog = fopen('listar.txt', "a")) {
    fwrite($savelog, $log . PHP_EOL . $log2);
    fclose($savelog);
}
```

> Note que o notepad.exe do windows requer \r\n pra suportar visualizar as quebras de linha, o `PHP_EOL` funciona como \n em todos sistemas operacionais mais modernos.

Comment: A concatenação resultou em solução... Valeu!